# Difficulty including the extra intellisense paths in the python linter's scope

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pylint

I am working with ros on ubuntu 16.04. Because of this I am working with a virtual environment for python 2.7 and the ros python modules (rospy for example). The "python.pythonPath" is set to the virtual environment and the ros modules are linked through "python.autoComplete.extraPaths".

This leads to the issue where the python linter raises an error for import rospy claiming that it can not import it. However, the python intellisense is still able detect and help with the rospy module (which makes sense due to the python.autoComplete.extraPaths setting).

Is there a way to include the extra paths for autoComplete for the linter as well? At this point, no longer including the virtual environment for the python path is not a desirable option so I am looking for a way to have the linter include the extra paths for ros python modules and the modules in the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the linter, but you can pass extra arguments to linters through your settings if the linter supports a way to pass extra directories, e.g. `python.linting.flake8Args`.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the mentioned linting error despite using the VSCode ROS extension and thus having `settings.json` automatically configured with `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"]` and my workspace paths.

I kept trying to add the paths with an *init-hook* to `python.lintin.pylintArgs` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55915465) **which never worked for me**.

Adding

```
[MASTER]
init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append("/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages")'
```

(and other paths if applicable) to `~/.pylintrc` finally did the trick.

As `echo $PYTHONPATH` was also set correctly by the extension,

```
[MASTER]
init-hook="from pylint.config import find_pylintrc;
import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(find_pylintrc()))"
```

even seems to even load all paths automatically.

**EDIT:**

On Ubuntu 18.04 with ROS Melodic and the latest VS Code with ROS, Python and Pylint extension, resolving `rospy` worked out of the box without configuring any `.pylintrc` when opening the workspace root folder in VS Code **after it was built at least once with catkin_make**.

To import custom Python modules from `<ws>/src/<package-name>/src`, I had to add the relative path `src/<package-name>/src` to `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths"`.

(Make sure to provide `<ws>/src/<package-name>/setup.py` and an empty `<ws>/src/<package-name>/src/<package-name>/__init__.py` as discussed [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/283140/how-to-import-python-modules-to-my-node/).)