# There is a way to eliminate the errors "Unable to import XXX" on VSCode?

Tags: python, import, visual-studio-code, pylint, gnuradio

I'm using VSCode to write my Python code and even the code run properly the pylint report the error: "Unable to import xxx"

see the figure below! how can I avoid it?
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007966/visual-studio-code-pylint-complaining-about-unable-to-import-xxx - might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved ... In my case I just needed to set another interpreter. just press F1 on vscode window and type Python:Select you will get right prompts